# Javascript :: prevent Uncaught Error when page is loaded

Tags: javascript, onload

I have an intersection function being fed by an input `<form>`

```
var chatArr = [];

function input() {
    var chat = document.getElementById("yousay").value;
    chatArr.push(chat);
    var words = chatArr.join(' ').match(/\S+/g);
       if(chat.length == 0){
        console.log("Mithras hears you")
       }
       else if(words.length > 1){   
         return words;
       }
       else{
         console.log(chat)
       };
}
```

then:

```
function setIntersection(a, b) {

    var result = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        if (b.indexOf(a[i]) !== -1 && result.indexOf(a[i]) === -1) {
            result.push(a[i]);
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

which, on its turn, passes into this function:

```
Song.prototype.lyricsIntersect = function(input) {


    var bestSong = null;
    var bestCount = -Infinity;

    for (var i in songs) {
        var currentCount = setIntersection(songs[i].lyrics, input()).length;
 (...)
```

When the page is loaded, however, the form is obviously empty, so I get:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined`

How do I prevent this error when page is loaded?

Comment: `function input` would have to return an Array. `b.indexOf` what?

Comment: What is the intent of the program?

Answer (score 0):

Check for Array Length before getting index of Array,

```
if(result.length > 0)
{
if (b.indexOf(a[i]) !== -1 && result.indexOf(a[i]) === -1) {
            result.push(a[i]);
        }
}
```

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this". We make an effort here to be a resource for knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

Try to declare your array like this:

```
var result = new Array(a.length);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding some protection to the if sentence, like this:

```
function setIntersection(a, b) {

    var result = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        if (
            typeof b != "undefined" && /* added protection */
            b.indexOf(a[i]) !== -1 && result.indexOf(a[i]) === -1) {
            result.push(a[i]);
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Now, as this code is inside a loop, the best you can do is avoid any iteration if b is undefined, so that:

```
function setIntersection(a, b) {

    var result = [];

    /* added protection */
    if(typeof b != "undefined") return result;

    for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        if (b.indexOf(a[i]) !== -1 && result.indexOf(a[i]) === -1) {
            result.push(a[i]);
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Basically, every value that the parameters of your function might be should be taken into account and add protection if necessary